# Can I use obd-elm327 or vgate i-car2 to get turn signal status?

Tags: obd-ii

I want to use `OBD` to get turn signal status on my car. My car is Toyota Yaris 2008. Is there any `OBD` products can do this or someone do the thing like this can share your experience for me?

Comment: did you get solution to the above issue?

Comment: unfortunately, I didn't get a solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn signal status is not covered by any official OBD2 PID. There may exist vendor specific (completely undocumented and secret) PIDs to get that, but I doubt it. If you are lucky, you can put your OBD2 adapter into monitor mode and listen for all signals the ECUs are broadcasting over the bus. Then though you have to reverse engineer what is which.